# Why is my content too wide for the container?

Tags: html, css

All of the widths and margins come out to a total of 99.96%, so it should fit just fine in the 100%. I understand that borders add width, so I've done `box-sizing: border-box;` but that doesn't seem to fix it. If I `float: left` then it works *okay* in Chrome, but I feel like that's a crappy workaround anyway and doesn't actually fix the problem.

Why doesn't it all fit on one line?

[Here's my jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/y1Ltq1fc/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#">
        1
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        2
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        3
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        4
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #BCCDDC;
    margin: 5% 25%
}

#container a {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0 6.66%;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

#container a:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0 !important;;
}

#container a:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`inline-block` elements aren't floated; they're inline, which means white space between elements is preserved.

You can fix this by removing the whitespace entirely between `<a>` tags: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/y1Ltq1fc/4/

```
    <a href="#">
        1
    </a><a href="#">
        2
    </a><a href="#">
        3
    </a><a href="#">
        4
    </a>
```

---

Alternatively, make the anchors `float: left` and put `overflow: auto` on the parent `#container`: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/y1Ltq1fc/9/

```
#container {
    overflow: auto;
}
#container a {
    float: left; /* automatically sets display:block */
    /* etc. */
}
```

[Here are some other techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297/901048), if you have a problem implementing the above.

Comment: Dammit. I've run into that problem before and I just completely forgot about it. My brain just said "oh it's inline-block, make sure to `white-space: nowrap` and completely forgot about it after that. Ugh. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`display: inline-block;` honors whitespace between elements, to fix it you can either:

**Remove the whitespace between the elements in the HTML**

```
<div id="container"> 
    <a href="#">1</a><a href="#">2</a><a href="#">3</a><a href="#">4</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1sgjh5c3/

**Make the font-size zero on the container in CSS**

```
#container {
    font-size: 0;
}
#container a {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jLhr8xcn/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers the whitespace between your elements is the issue here.

Though you can use `float: left` here, you just have to keep two things in mind:

- when your container only has floating elements it doesn't stretch up use `overflow: auto` to fix that
- the missing 0.04% might look off depending on your screen size, 
  so you may want to change the alignment for the last element

---

```
#container {
  overflow: auto;
}
#container a {
  float: left;
}
#container a:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with manually setting the margins, you could use `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14dqmu1x/)</kbd>

Just add the two styles to the parent, and remove the margin from the child

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: I [wish flex was better supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) in older IE.